# Can we use sliced inverse regression for p> n

Tags: regression

I've been using sliced inverse regression for my work and I use the dr package in R to estimate the parameter vector.  This works well when p < n, where p is the number of covariates and 'n' is the sample size.  However, when p > n, I could not do any estimation using the dr() package.  It says that p must be less than n.  But, when I looked and the K.C.Li's original paper in 1991, I did not see any restriction like that.  I really appreciate it if someone can direct me to a link or an R package that can handle the p>n case for sliced inverse regression.  Or if you can explain why we can't use it when p>n.

Comment: I don't know what sliced inverse regression is, but regression in general cannot be solved when $p>n$, unless you employ some sort of regularization.

Answer (score 0):

In Li's original paper, he mentions briefly that the assumption that $$Y = f(\beta^T X, \epsilon),$$ where $\beta$ is a $p \times k$ matrix, becomes redundant when $k = p$. This is because the goal of sufficient dimension reduction is to find some map $\Pi: \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ such that $\mathbb{E}(Y|\, X) = \mathbb{E}(Y|\,\Pi (X))$ where $k<p$. Essentially we are looking to compress the information given by $X$ to be as dense as possible without losing any information. This method is often used as a tool for visualization of data or as a pre-processing tool for other methods which perform better on lower dimensional spaces such as kernel regression. When viewed in this light, lifting $X$ to higher dimensions wouldn't be useful as it won't tell you any more information about the expectation value of $Y|X$ than $X$ itself would. For more information, see [Sufficient Dimension Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_dimension_reduction).